# How to bypass confirmation prompts of an external process?

Tags: perl, groovy, groovyshell

How can I convert this Perl code to Groovy?

How to bypass confirmation prompts of an external process?

I am trying to convert a Perl script to Groovy. The program is loading/delete maestro (job scheduling) jobs automatically. The problem is the delete command will prompt for confirmation (Y/N) on every single job that it finds.  I tried the process execute in groovy but will stop at the prompts. The Perl script is writing bunch of Ys to the stream and print it to the handler( if I understood it correctly) to avoid stopping. I am wondering how to do the same thing in Groovy ?

Or any other approach to execute a command and somehow write Y on every confirmation prompt.

Perl Script:

```
 $maestrostring="";
 while ($x < 1500) {
    $maestrostring .= "y\n";
    $x++;
 }

  # delete the jobs
  open(MAESTRO_CMD, "|ssh mserver /bin/composer delete job=pserver#APPA@") 
  print MAESTRO_CMD $maestrostring;
  close(MAESTRO_CMD);
```

This is my working groovy code:

```
    def deleteMaestroJobs (){
            ...
    def commandSched ="ssh $maestro_server /bin/composer delete sched=$primary_server#$app_acronym$app_level@"
    def commandJobs  ="ssh $maestro_server /bin/composer delete job=$primary_server#$app_acronym$app_level@"

    try {
        executeCommand commandJobs
    }
    catch (Exception ex ){
        throw new Exception("Error executing the Maestro Composer [DELETE]")
    }

    try {
        executeCommand commandSched
    }
    catch (Exception ex ){
        throw new Exception("Error executing the Maestro Composer [DELETE]")
    }
}


    def executeCommand(command){
        def process = command.execute()
        process.withWriter { writer ->
          writer.print('y\n' * 1500)
        }
       process.consumeProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
       process.waitFor()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct translation would be:

```
'ssh mserver /bin/composer delete job=pserver#APPA@'.execute().withWriter { writer ->
    writer.print('y\n' * 1500)
}
```

Comment: Careful though...  I guess this is churning output, and if you don't read the streams, it's going to choke and block

Comment: Good point. I think the perl version would suffer from the same problem.

Comment: @ataylor I tested your approach and it seems promising, however, it only worked on the fist prompt and deleted it but for the rest it wont stop but wont delete them either if that make sense.

Comment: I've updated the answer to write one big string of ys instead of writing the ys individually, like the perl example.  Does that help?

Comment: @tim_yates does consumeProcessOutput consider reading the stream?

Answer (score 0):

An other option is to use `yes`:

```
system( qq(ssh mserver "yes y | /bin/composer delete job=pserver#APPA\@") );
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard Unix program `yes` is made for this sort of thing.

```
yes | ssh mserver /bin/composer delete job=pserver#APPA@
```

Note that `yes` will output an infinite amount given the chance.  But when used with a pipe like this, it just stays one step ahead of the other end of the pipe, and waits for it to catch up reading, and finally quits when the OS gives it a SIGPIPE.

Comment: When I used this method it is throwing -java.io.IOException: y|ssh: not found exception